# Storing encrypted password with fernet and key generated from any text,

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, password-encryption, hashlib

I'm looking for a way to encrypt main password using short key/pin and decrypt it by this pin every time.
I tried to generate hash (sha256) from short key given by user and cut off the hash to desired length, decode it to bytecode and use as Fernet

Piece of code:

```
pin = self.pin_ent.get()
key: str = hashlib.sha256(pin.encode()).hexdigest()[10:-10]
f = Fernet(key.decode())
```

but python rise the error

```
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

Comment: I think it's because Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean with "desired length". SHA-256 creates a 32 byte hash value (without the hex encoding that you added). You just need to base64url encode it, *as the error description suggests*.

A PIN is not suitable for encryption purposes as it is too easy to try all possible PIN values, and try to decrypt the stored password. If you'd use a normal-strength password to encrypt the other password (which seems counter-productive, but hey) then SHA-256 is not secure either, you'd have to use a PBKDF such as PBKDF2 to strengthen the password.